# For which values of $c$ does the matrices form a basis for $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrices 
$\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & c  \\
    0       & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}
    0      & 1  \\
    c       & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 0  \\
    1       & c \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}
    c       & 0  \\
    0       & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

For which values of $c \in \mathbb{C}$ the above matrices form a basiss for the vector space $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$?

Since $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$ is of dimention 4, it suffices to find values of $c$ for which the matrices are linearly indepenedent.
So I looked a t the equation :

$a\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & c  \\
    0       & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}
    0      & 1  \\
    c       & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} + c\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 0  \\
    1       & c \\
\end{bmatrix}+d\begin{bmatrix}
    c       & 0  \\
    0       & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}=0$

Solving those for $c$ gives $c= \frac{-b}{a}=\frac{-a}{e}=\frac{-e}{d}=\frac{-d}{b}$ So then $ a,b,d ,e \neq 0$. I noticed that $c=1$ or $c=0$ gives rise to contradiction. I feel like given $c$ and $a$ we can solve the others, So the solution should be $\mathbb{C}-\{1\}$?

I'm not sure about my reasonings.

Comment: There is a certain 4 by 4 determinant you should look at...

Comment: First of all, fix your notation, because you use $c$ in two different contexts.

Comment: @kimchilover on my linalg course, determinants were a lot after such problems (but other metods to check linear dependence/independence were provided).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wknow the canonical basis of $\mathcal M_{2\times2}(\mathbf C)$:
$$E_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix},\quad E_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix},\quad E_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad E_4=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
In this basis, the deerminant of the given system of matrices is
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&c \\ c&1&0&0\\
0&c&1&0\\
0&0&c&1
\end{vmatrix}.$$
Can you calculate this determinant, expanding by the first row, for instance?